# Ссылка и выполнение кода

Tags: php, html

Скажите пожалуйста как сделать так. На странице есть ссылка нужно сделать так что бы при нажатие на нее непереходил по ссылке а выполнял поределенный код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="qweqwe()">ссылка</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function qweqwe() {
  alert('Выполняйся, код!');
 }
</script>
```

Comment: только еще добавить

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

Comment: @flef, либо `return false`